# javascript instance sharing in nested functions

Tags: javascript

In the js code specified below -

```
var tclass = function(){
   this.func2=function(){console.log('func2')};
   this.b={
      func1: function(){console.log('func1')}
   }
}
```

how do i call func2 inside func1 on the same instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to keep a reference to both `this` and that function in the closure.

```
var tclass = function(){
   var obj = this;
   function func2(){console.log('func2')};
   this.func2 = func2;
   this.b={
      func1: function(){ obj.func2(); }
   }
}
```

Also it's more useful to declare functions with actual function declaration statements:

```
function tclass() {
  // ...
}
```